# Node API callback communicate with a Server websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a websocket running on Node with `socket.io`. You can connect to the socket for a real-time application

I also have `RESTful` API in case you want to perform a very specific task without opening a web socket.

How can I link say a `GET` request to the server socket.io so that I can then relay back the information in `res.json()`?

Comment: This question is going to depend entirely on your application. Typically you'd have a database that both services share for information but there are definitely other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about calling function and passing response logic in callback?

```
function getUsers(callback) {
  var users = [{id:1, username:'batman'}, {id:2, username:'superman'}];
  callback(users);
}

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
   getUsers(function(data) {
     res.status(200).json({success: true, data: data});
   });
});

io.on("connection", function(socket){
   socket.on("/users", function(){
     getUsers(function(data) {
       socket.emit('response:/users', {success: true, data: data});
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: How is `sockets.on("/users")` being called? Is that a Socket.IO feature that it will listen to incoming request endpoints?

Comment: no, socket.on('/users', function() {}) is event handler, You emit it from clientside by doing io.emit('/users', {})  than doing ajax call or something else. and on clientside You write io.on('response:/users', function(respnse){console.log(response);});

Comment: So no, that's not what I want then. That was my point. These should be two separate events running. But the API endpoints would internally make a call to the websocket server to pass information

Comment: You wanted to do normal http get call and also socket call. So I made 1 function and passed it to both http get handler and also socket event handler. Calling http get from socket is not good idea because it will do http response than socket response even You call it from socket.